# Extending the UserCredentialsConfig in NextAuth

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I have a typescript error due to a modification I have made to the NextAuth auth options for the CredentialsProvider function that accepts two additional values, `formPassword: string;` `newUser: boolean;`. These values are not used in the credentials call from the library, but are used as conditionals to determine the response that happens. While the code works, I have errors because both properties don't exist as value in the interface

```
(property) authorize: (credentials: Record<"email" | "password", string> | undefined, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<...>
```

How can I extend what I believe to be the `UserCredentialsConfig` interface to be able to add these keys and remove the error?

Code:

```
// Credential provider configuration for NextAuth
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      // Authorization = Using a text form with email/password
      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log(credentials);

        const { email, password } = credentials as {
          email: string;
          password: string;
        };
        const formPassword = credentials?.formPassword;
        const authFormType = credentials?.newUser ? formPassword : password;

        try {
          if (!email || !password) {
            console.log('No Email or Password Provided');
            return null;
          }

          const user = await prisma.appUsers.findUnique({
            where: {
              email: email,
            },
          });

          if (!user) {
            console.log('User does not exist');
            return null;
          }

          const isPasswordValid = await confirmPasswordHash(
            authFormType,
            user.password
          );

          if (!isPasswordValid) {
            console.log('Password is not correct');
            return null;
          }

          return {
            email: user.email,
            name: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
            firstName: user.firstName,
            lastName: user.lastName,
            id: user.id,
            avatar: user.avatar,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
```